# Заполнение списка в одну строку

Tags: python

Как мне заполнить список размера N целыми числами в одну строку.
Есть такой код(в чем тут ошибка?):

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(input().split()) for i in range(n)]
print(*a)
```

Comment: что с этим кодом не так? Что вообще нужно сделать?

Comment: `builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: не работает именно в том случае, если надо вводить данные в одну строку

Comment: Вам непонятен текст ошибки?

Comment: нет не понятен.

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что аргументом функции int() должна быть строка или число, а не список, как у вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = list(map(int, input("Input list of INT:").split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [int(x) for x in input("Enter space-separated list of integers").split()]
```